# Convert a simple json object to Dictionary List in (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a simple json:

```
{
    "timestamp": "38519277!12/14/2018 08:35:17",
    "entity": "Account",
    "entity": "Contact",
    "entity": "Case"
}
```

That I need to add to Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> objects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

The key is entity and the value is always the same timestamp. I'm not sure how to proceed. This is something I have not done before. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: This is not even a valid json. You have duplicate `entity` keys in it...

Comment: It should be:
`{
    "timestamp": "38519277!12/14/2018 08:35:17",
    "entity": ["Account", "Contact", "Case"]
}` What you have now is not valid and cant be deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

Here...

```
string json = @"{""timestamp"":""38519277!12/14/2018 08:35:17"",""entity"":""Account""}";

Dictionary<string, string> objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

for more details :

[How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to use dictionary, the only way is to give value part as object type or dynamic.

```
Dictionary<string, object> objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

if you are going to use JsonConvert, then [use this Example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Test
{
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<string> entity { get; set; }
}
```

...and your json object that looks like this (because as pointed out in the comments, your current json object is not valid)

```
"{ \"timestamp\": \"38519277!12 / 14 / 2018 08:35:17\", \"entity\": [\"Account\", \"Contact\", \"Case\"] }"
```

After deserializing `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);`

This is the line of code that you want:

```
Dictionary<string, string> objects = obj.entity.ToDictionary(x => x, x => obj.timestamp);
```